# details in one Row without any redundancy in the CATID

Tags: php, sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

```
$query1 = "select * 
             from linkat_link 
            where emailuser = '$email2' 
               or linkname ='$domain_name2' 
         ORDER BY date desc 
            LIMIT $From,$PageNO";
```

> id   catid      discription            price
>   ------------------------------------
>   1          1       domain name       100
>   2         1       book                          50
>   3        2       hosting                    20
>   4        2       myservice               20

in this script i have one problem , if i have an ID for Each Cantegory , i have some duplicated CATID which has different content but shares the same CATID, i need to make any duplicated CATID to show in one , and all the discription will be in the same line (Cell)  on the same row .
So Each CatID will have all the details in one Row without any redundancy in the CATID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
  SELECT t.catid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(t.description),
         GROUP_CONCAT(t.price)
    FROM LINKAT_LINK t
   WHERE t.emailuser = mysql_real_escape_string($email2)
      OR t.linkname = mysql_real_escape_string($domain_name2)
GROUP BY t.catid
ORDER BY t.date DESC
   LIMIT mysql_real_escape_string($From), mysql_real_escape_string($PageNO)
```

...will return:

```
catid   description        price
--------------------------------
1       domain name,book   100,50
2       hosting,myservice  20,20
```

See the [documentation for what the `GROUP_CONCAT` function does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

### How to print it to screen using PHP?

---

Use:

```
<?php

 $query1 = "SELECT t.catid,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(t.description) AS grp_desc,
                   GROUP_CONCAT(t.price) AS grp_price
              FROM LINKAT_LINK t
             WHERE t.emailuser = mysql_real_escape_string($email2)
                OR t.linkname = mysql_real_escape_string($domain_name2)
          GROUP BY t.catid
          ORDER BY t.date DESC
             LIMIT mysql_real_escape_string($From), mysql_real_escape_string($PageNO)";

 $result = mysql_query($query1);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "CatID:{$row['catid']} <br>" .
     "Description : {$row['grp_desc']} <br>" .
     "Price : {$row['grp_price']} <br><br>";
 } ?>
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/u/public_html/bill2.php on line 15

Comment: @alkitbi: Don't forget to vote for things, in addition to marking answers.  You can upvote by clicking the up arrow, above the zero in the upper left corner to my answer.  You don't have enough reputation to downvote yet...

Comment: ok 
how can do this :

1       domain name 100
        book        50 
----------------------
2       hosting     20
        myservice   20

Comment: <p>1 domain name 100 book 50<br>
---------------------- <br>
2 hosting 20 myservice 20 </p>

Comment: The normal way there is no problem, but the figure is not on the tables organized